# If you're using both View Binding and Data Binding, what are the generated binding classes called?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-viewbinding

View Binding generates the name of the binding class from the name of the layout file, but Data Binding reportedly generates the same name. What if you're using both?

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var dataBinding: ?
```

I realize you wouldn't need to use both for the same activity, but if you've enabled both at the module level, how does the compiler resolve this naming issue for each activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this: [view-binding#data-binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#data-binding)

> View binding and data binding both generate binding classes that you can use to reference views directly

So, it just create one class: ActivityMainBinding

Comment: Well, it says "classes," plural. Thanks for the response, though.